# How to avoid network latency in performance testing

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

We have servers which are installed on other Las Vegas and currently we need to perform performance testing with jmeter from SAN Francisco office.I am pretty sure doing so there will be network latency added to response times.Do you have any idea how can we avoid that.

Comment: This site is for programming questions, not networking setup.

Comment: it is for performance testing.I asked here if any networking guy come across that kind of issue

Comment: You can't avoid network latency at all, let alone for performance testing. Your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't avoid network latency, but at least minimize its' consequences to your test results.

Just place your load generator instances (Jmeter servers) as close as possible to testing target. Ideally they should be in the same data center (take a look at [Amazon EC2 instances](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) for instance).

In this case your latency will not have a huge effect on performance results, since it will be relatively small.

But remember that network latency is an everyday part of any network communication and you have to take it into account also. It can have major effect on your system in production, especially for the users which are not closely "situated" to your data centers.

Answer (score 2):

Actually JMeter stores Latency separately and as per [The Load Reports](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65153-the-load-reports) guide

> The response time that is required to receive a response from the server is the sum of the **response time + latency**.

JMeter .jtl result file looks as follows:

[image: Latency]

So a very simple formula like `=B2-L2` will help you to determine response time without Latency metric, however it isn't something which is being normally done as latency matters.

Comment: how can we open jtl file in excel?

Comment: JMeter has 2 results output formats: CSV and XML. Excel or equivalent have natural support of CSV files. If your jtl file comes in XML format you can change it to CSV by setting `jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv` property in user.properties file. See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) guide for information on different JMeter properties and ways of setting nad overriding them